# what queryset is required?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
PHONE_CHOICES = (
    ('home', 'Home'),
    ('home2', 'Home 2'),
    ('mobi', 'Mobile'),
    ('mobi2', 'Mobile 2'),
    ('work', 'Work'),
    ('work2', 'Work 2'),
)

class ClientPhone(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
    phone_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=PHONE_CHOICES)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=24)
```

I know `ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=i_clientKEY).latest('created')` Will get me the latest phone number entered into the db, but I want to be able to get the latest phone numbers for 'home', 'home2', 'mobi', etc...*(all)* for a client.

How do I get a queryset to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**latest()** returns a single query object, not a list, so you will get tha latest tel. record of related person.

If you wish to get the latest nmber for each phone_type, you must execute diffrent sql queries, so that means you must write diffrent queries for each phone_type...

@Aldarund: using **phone_type__in** helps you to get latest record with phone_type of one of the elements of the list(one with the latest creation time.), but not one result for each element in the list

Comment: I thought that might be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add another argument to filter like this:
ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=i_clientKEY,phone_type='home').latest('created')

Comment: can I do that like `ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=i_clientKEY,phone_type='home',phone_type='home2',phone_type='mobi',phone_type=...).latest('created')` for all of them?

Comment: You can do it like this:
ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=i_clientKEY,phone_type__in=['home','home2','mobi',...]).latest('created')